# Adicionar HTML de outra página

Tags: javascript, html

Precisava adicionar o conteúdo de outra página em `HTML`, tipo, abro a página http://www.site1.com.br/teste.html e dentro do `HTML` dessa página teria um evento ou algum `javascript` que carregasse o http://www.site2.com.br/arquivos/site1.html, mas sem mudar a `URL`.

Comment: Pesquise por iframe, é exatamente oque quer

Comment: Valeu, vou colocar como resposta :)

Answer (score 2):

OK, resolvi usando o iframe.
Para referência futura:

```
 <iframe src="http://site2.com.br/arquivos/site1.html"></iframe>
```

:D